# Is this a transitive graph in graph theory

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple graph which has the following property. If $(u,v)\in E$ and $(v,s)\in E$ then $(u,s)\in E$. What kind of graph is this? Does it have any name and special property?

Comment: Per @bof, you may want to change the hypotheses so as to stop all such graphs being merely collections of disconnected points.

Comment: FYI, strictly speaking, to write '$(u,v)\in E$' is wrong, at least according to what is currently the usual formalisation of 'graph' via set theory (see e.g. Diestel: *Graph Theory*); in that formalism, a simple graph has *two-sets* as edges, and $(u,v)$ in set-theory is *not* equal to the two-set containing only $u$ and $v$. (Of course, $(u,v)$ in the usual formalisation *is* a two-set, but another one:  $(u,v)=\{u,\{u,v\}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Such a graph is a disjoint union of complete graphs. Indeed, it's easy to prove by induction on the number of vertices of any connected subgraph that any connected subgraph is complete.

Comment: A simple group with the stated property is an *empty graph*, a graph with no edges. Because, if $(u,v)\in E,$ then $(v,u)\in E$ and $(u,u)\in E,$ so the graph is not simple.

Comment: @bof True. My statement is still correct though ;)